# Calling Mac.getInstance with any algorithm Returns java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException

Tags: java, android

I searched the internet for this problem I found only  one solution which stats

> "Copy sunjce_provider.jar from $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext to the lib
>   directory of the container.
>
> Adding the following line to my code:
>
> java.security.Security.addProvider(new
>   com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE());"

But I do not get it.What is lib directory of the container??And Where am I supposed to Add this line "java.security.Security.addProvider(new
 com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE())"

I am running ubuntu machine and writing android app using android studio.

Comment: There is no support for `com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE` in Android. What algorithms are you trying?

Comment: hmacSHA256  algorithm

Comment: Nikolay Elenkov's "Android Security Internals" book indicates that this is supported, though he has it as `HmacSha256`. You might wish to provide a [mcve], showing your code plus the full Java stack trace.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am facing a similar problem and posted a new question- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47678782/hmacsha256-algorithm-in-android-api-23