# HmacSHA256 algorithm in Android API 23

Tags: java, c#, android, sha256

I am trying to generate hash value in my Android app (API 23). I followed this link- https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/Mac.html and below code should work as per it.

```
Mac hmacSha256 = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
```

But this gives compile time error-

[image]

> java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException

I searched and tried few solutions from across other Stackoverflow posts but they didn't work.

Tried this- `MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");` got same error.

My overall intention is to convert the below C# code in Java so I can use it in my Android app-

```
string GenerateAuthToken(string verb, string resourceType, string resourceId, string date, string key, string keyType, string tokenVersion)
{
    var hmacSha256 = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256 { Key = Convert.FromBase64String(key) };

    verb = verb ?? "";
    resourceType = resourceType ?? "";
    resourceId = resourceId ?? "";

    string payLoad = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n{3}\n{4}\n",
            verb.ToLowerInvariant(),
            resourceType.ToLowerInvariant(),
            resourceId,
            date.ToLowerInvariant(),
            ""
    );

    byte[] hashPayLoad = hmacSha256.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payLoad));
    string signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hashPayLoad);

    return System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "type={0}&ver={1}&sig={2}",
        keyType,
        tokenVersion,
        signature));
}
```

So I am just going and converting each line manually step by step and stuck at this point. Any ideas I can make this work?

Comment: `MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")` works fine, see: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-security/blob/v0.8.0/security/src/main/java/com/commonsware/cwac/security/SignatureUtils.java#L41-L46

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried that but it gives same exception

Comment: Please provide the complete Java stack trace showing the exception and the code that is triggering the exception.

Comment: I see no exception.

Answer (score 0):

You typed the algorithm incorrectly
It's HmacSHA256 not hmacSHA256

You need to be careful when choosing the algorithms because they're case sensitive.

From your snapshot I can see that you used

```
Mac hmacSHA256 = Mac.getInstance("hmacSHA256");
```

It's incorrect because you're trying to get the instance of hmacSHA256 witch does not exists!

The correct one would be

```
Mac hmacSHA256 = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA245");
```

The first **H** should be on caps

Comment: The snapshot that you've attached it contains `Mac hmacSHA256 = Mac.getInstance("hmacSHA256");` witch is wrong it should be `Mac hmacSHA256 = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");`

Comment: They are not case sensitive. There is no such thing as "HmacSHA245".

Comment: @PedroCavaleiro I have tried these possible combinations.

Comment: @SouvikGhosh check out this example, and double check the imports https://www.jokecamp.com/blog/examples-of-creating-base64-hashes-using-hmac-sha256-in-different-languages/#java